# Improve performance of Datetime operation in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have a big data set that I need to date operation, and as it is taking too long, I was wondering if there is any other way to boost up the speed. Data frame looks like following:

```
Date, Month
2017-01-01, 0
2017-01-01, 1
2017-01-01, 2
```

I need to create another column that adds month column to date column, so it would look like following:

```
Date, Month, newDate
2017-01-01, 0, 2017-01-01
2017-01-01, 1, 2017-02-01
2017-01-01, 2, 2017-03-01
```

My current method is using apply function and relativedelta method like:

```
def newDateCalc(self, row):
return row[0] + relativedelta(months = row[1])
```

`df['newDate'] = df[['Date', 'Month']].apply(lambda row: newDateCalc(row), axis = 1)`

Thank you for your help in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my vectorized attempt:

```
df['newDate'] = (df.Date.values.astype('M8[M]') + 
                 df.Month.values * np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).astype('M8[D]')
```

Result:

```
In [106]: df
Out[106]:
        Date  Month    newDate
0 2017-01-01      0 2017-01-01
1 2017-01-01      1 2017-02-01
2 2017-01-01      2 2017-03-01
```

Comment: @Hojin, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.transform` with `relativedelta`:

```
In [960]: df.transform(lambda x: x['Date'] + relativedelta(months=x['Month']), axis=1)
Out[960]: 
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-02-01
2   2017-03-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```